# Computer Display Name Not Updating In AD

Tags: windows, active-directory

I have a computer in Active Directory. When this machine was initially added to our domain, I named it "PA-WB-TRAININGT". I named it this on the actual machine itself (Windows system settings when joining the domain).

A few minutes later, I went back into Windows system settings on the machine, and renamed it to "PA-WB-TRAINING4". However, for some reason, in Active Directory, it remained listed as "PA-WB-TRAININGT".

It has now been well over 1.5 months, and the name in AD is still "PA-WB-TRAININGT".

If I right click the machine in AD and go to properties, it lists computer name as TRAINING4, and DNS name begins with TRAINING4. It seems it is just the name in the AD listing that is not updating.

I do not personally have access to the backend of AD (such as being able to run scripts to update this listing manually or something".

I was wondering the following: Is there something I can do on the machine itself to make this update push into AD properly, or will I have to contact a different department (which has deeper access into AD than I do) to change it?

Picture attached it how it looks in AD (you can see the "TRAININGT" version behind the properties window and as the title of the properties window).

[Image of issue in AD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShdCQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Renaming the computer in the System Control Panel will not update the name in AD. It needs to be renamed in AD Users and Computers or a similar tool.  For future reference, the PowerShell cmdlet Rename-Computer will rename it in both places.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-computer?view=powershell-7.2

Comment: I've been renaming computers via their control panel applet my entire career and it always updates the name in AD (up until something weird happened today, which is how I found this thread). The Rename-Computer cmdlet works (and has worked) exactly the same. Renaming from ADUC has historically caused issues/not worked in my experience.